# Java compareTo (Object obj)

Tags: java, compareto

I've given an assigment and its the last day of itself. I did most of it but on the last question I have a problem with creating a compareTo() function.

Here is what it does want from us ;

compareTo

public int compareTo(java.lang.Object other)

```
Specified by:
    compareTo in interface java.lang.Comparable
```

Here is what I did

```
public int compareTo(Object obj)
{
Document tmp = (Document)obj;
if(this.text < tmp.text)
{
/* instance lt received */
return -1;
}
else if(this.text > tmp.text)
{
/* instance gt received */
return 1;
}
/* instance == received */
return 0;
}
```

Here is my whole Document.java file

class Document
{
    private String text;

```
/**
* Default constructor;  Initialize amount to zero.
*/
public Document()
{
    text = "";
}

/**
* Default constructor;  Initialize text to input value
* @param text New text value
*/
public Document(String text)
{
    this.text = text;
}

/**
* Returns as a string the contents of the Document.
*/
public String toString()
{
    return text;
}
```

and Here is the test file of itself.

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Homework2 extends Document {

```
/** ======================
* ContainsKeyword
* Returns true if the Document
* object passed in contains keyword as a substring
* of its text property.
* ======================
*/
public static boolean ContainsKeyword(Document docObject, String keyword)
{
    if (docObject.toString().indexOf(keyword,0) >= 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}


public static void main(String[] args){

    Email email1= new Email("Programming in Java",
            "Larry", "Curly", "Programming");
    Email email2 = new Email("Running marathons",
            "Speedy", "Gonzales", "races");

    System.out.println(email1);

    File file1 = new File("Some Java file", "file.txt");
    File file2 = new File(
            "Boluspor wins against Besiktas. Muahahahaha", 
    "bolutas.txt");

    Document doc = new Document (
    "ok?,ok?,ok?,ok?,ok?,ok?,ok?,ok?,ok?,ok?,ok?,ok?");

    System.out.println("\n"+file1);

    System.out.println("\nWhich contains Java?");
    if (ContainsKeyword(email1,"Java")) System.out.println(" Email1");
    if (ContainsKeyword(email2,"Java")) System.out.println(" Email2");
    if (ContainsKeyword(file1,"Java")) System.out.println(" File1");
    if (ContainsKeyword(file2,"Java")) System.out.println(" File2");

    Document [] da = new Document [5];
    da[0] = email1;
    da[1] = email2;
    da[2] = file1;
    da[3] = file2;
    da[4] = doc;
    Arrays.sort(da);
    System.out.println("\nAfter sort:");
    for(Document d : da){
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
}
```

What I wanted to ask is, I cannot compare the objects from my Email.java and File.java , I can do anything else but the last part which starts with Document [] da... That part gives an error. What am I doing wrong here?

The error is ;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Email cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1144)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1079)
at Homework2.main(Homework2.java:53)
```

UPLOAD ** Here is my Email and File Class..

```
/**
* First define class for Email, derive from Document
*/
class Email extends Document
{
    private String sender;
    private String recipient;
    private String title;
    private String body;

    /**
    * Constructors
    */
    public Email()
    {
        super();
        sender = "";
        recipient = "";
        title = "";
        body = "";
    }

    public Email(String body, String sender, String recipient, String title)
    {

        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipient = recipient;
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
    }

   // ======================
   // Various accessor and mutator methods
   // ======================
    public String getSender()
    {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender)
    {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getRecipient()
    {
        return recipient;
    }

    public void setRecipient(String recipient)
    {
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getBody(){
        return body;
    }  
    public void getBody(String body){
        this.body = body;
    }

   /**
  * Returns as a string the contents of the text fields concatenated
  * together.  Uses super.toString to get the parent's text.
  */
   public String toString()
  { 
return "Sender:" + sender + ",Recipient:" + recipient + ",Title:" + title + ",Body:" + body + " " +
 super.toString();
  }
} // Email
```

and File ;

```
/**
* Next define class for File, derive from Document
* For brevity, short one-line methods are defined here in the
* header.
*/
class File extends Document
{
private String pathname;

/**
* Constructors.
*/
public File()
{
    super();
    pathname = "";
}

public File(String body, String pathname)
{
    super(body);
    this.pathname = pathname;
}

// ======================
// Various accessor and mutator methods
// ======================
public void setPathname(String s)
{
    pathname = s;
}

public String getPathname()
{
    return pathname;
}

/**
* Returns as a string the contents of the text fields concatenated
* together.  Uses super.toString to get the parent's text.
*/
public String toString()
{
    return "Pathname " + pathname + " Body " + super.toString();
}
```

} // File

Comment: Assigment of mine, which has 10 questions in it and 1.5 weeks given. And its the part of last question which I stuck.

Comment: You haven't shown us anything about your Email or File classes, nor have you shown us where your compareTo method is implemented. Why does your Homework2 class extend Document?

Comment: you shouldn't be using `<` to compare Strings they are objects themselves you should be using their `compareTo` method as in `public int compareTo(Object obj) { return this.text.compareTo(obj.text);}`. Though you might want to add some error detection to that.

Comment: I am adding my email and file classes right now.

Comment: Include code that is critically relevant to the problem, not the entire thing.  It would help you get an answer quicker, and help you as a student to narrow down the problem better.  See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Where did you put the `compareTo` method?  If you're trying to sort an array of `Document`s, you need to have Document implement Comparable (or pass in a Comparator):

```
public class Document implements Comparable<Document> {
```

Or, if for some bizarre reason you're not allowed to use generics:

```
public class Document implements Comparable {
```

Then put `compareTo` within `Document`.

Answer (score 1):

The exact reason it is failing is because you are trying to call `Arrays.sort` on a class that does not implement comparable

> Implementing Comparable allows
>
> ```
>   calling Collections.sort and Collections.binarySearch
>   calling Arrays.sort and Arrays.binarySearch
>   using objects as keys in a TreeMap
>   using objects as elements in a TreeSet
> ```

Email did not implement the Comparable interface

use

```
public class Email implements Comparable<Email>
```

read this to do yourself a favor http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10

The other note is you said you want to compare

> Email.java and File.java

You will need a custom function for that based on the logic.

compareTo is used to compare two instances of the same type.  It also means that the function lives in the Email class

```
Email myEmail = new Email();
Email hisEmail = new Email();

myEmail.compareTo(hisEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is in the error message.

You can only sort objects for classes which implement Comparable. Your class does not.

As you are sorting a number of different types you may want to provide a custom Comparator instead, or make Document implement Comparable.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Here is my whole Document.java file

```
class Document implements Comparable { //this line is your solution.
 private String text;

/**
* Default constructor;  Initialize amount to zero.
*/
public Document()
{
    text = "";
}

/**
* Default constructor;  Initialize text to input value
* @param text New text value
*/
....}
```

Comment: I tried both solutions but it still cant sort the given inputs :/ 

Changed the required things. Extended it with Comparable also but Do I have to create an another method for also email and file ?

Comment: 1.) you can compareTo only Comparable things, so yes you need to implement for email and file.
2.) since you email and file extends Document which is compareable, email and file is also comparable as long as you provide it with "text" (I mean you should call super("someInfo") )

so in your email constructor (this one : public Email(String body, String sender, String recipient, String title) ) you forget to call super(title)